# has_many nested form with has_one inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, simple-form

I'm having a similar issue to 
[has_many nested form with a has_one nested form within it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342210/has-many-nested-form-with-a-has-one-nested-form-within-it)

Basically trying to create tasks at the same time I'm creating a client, some of those tasks may be recurring which is handled through a has_one relationship to a recurring model.

So.

Client Model

```
    attr_accessible :tasks_attributes
    has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['task_type'].blank? }
```

Task model

```
     belongs_to :client
     has_one :recurring, :dependent => :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :recurring, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['recurring_type'].blank? }
     attr_accessible :recurring_attributes
```

Clients_controller

```
def new
@client = Client.new 
@task = @client.tasks.build
```

Client/_form

```
    <table id="tasks" class="table table-striped">
      <%=f.simple_fields_for :tasks, :wrapper => false  do |task|%>
        <tr class="fields>
                <td><%=task.input :task_type, :label => "Task Type", :collection => Task::TASK_TYPES %></td>
                <td>
                  <%= task.simple_fields_for :recurring, @task.build_recurring do |recur|%>
                    <%= recur.input :recurring_type, :as => :select, :collection => Recurring::RECUR_TYPES %>
                  <%end%>
                </td>
                <td><%= task.input :due_date, :as => :datepicker, :label => "Next Due Date"%></td>
                <td><%= task.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %></td>
            <%end%>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks, :data => { :target => "#tasks" } %>
```

I can get the form to display correctly and it now adds and removes tasks correctly.
But when I submit I get a

```
    undefined method `build_recurring' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm now on the 5th attempt at doing this in different ways and it's driving me insane.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does the Recurring model look like? You have Tasks in an association with a model called Recurring - does it exist?

Comment: Recurring model belongs_to task. It basically just holds recurrence criteria for the task where necessary.

Comment: I might be tempted to denormalise the database structure abit if the Recurring model only contains the recurring_type attribute and put into Task. However apart from that have you tried the simple_form associations https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations ? Maybe something like <%= task.association :recurring, collection: Recurring::RECUR_TYPES %>

Comment: There are other reasons why I want to keep recurring separate. It seems to work if I just delete thre recurrence bit, but all I'm adding is a value ona dropdown and it's not accepting that. Really bloody irritating.

Comment: Just to explain, it's important to keep the recurrence criteria separate from teh individual instance of the task, since we need to recognise that recurrence once the individual task has been modified (as a way to provide infinite recurrence without persisting infinite things in the database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming because of reject_if. It is rejecting the blank fields which when error comes and because of this that field is not showing up.

Removing reject_if for blank can be changed to nil, and after that validation can be handled as regular validation as handled.

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem. i.e. still not able to add multiple tasks with recurring data.